# Перед подлинным выражением слово "надпись". Обязательно ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

В руках у них флаги и плакаты с надписями «Я хочу жить в свободной стране, а ты?», «Украина начинается с тебя».

Обязательно ли перед кавычками ставить двоеточие?

У Розенталя:

если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, надпись, выражение и т.п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например:

Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные, также отдаются напрокат и починяются старые» (Пушкин).

У Улицкой:

Последним уроком было рисование. Рисовали из головы корзину с цветами и подписью на красной ленте «Поздравляю маму...».

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь дал конкретный, однозначный ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Попав в тень чуть зеленеющих лип писатели первым долгом бросились к пёстро раскрашенной будочке с надписью «Пиво и воды» (Булгаков).

Comment: В художественной литературе немало вольностей с пунктуацией. Вы это хорошо знаете.